# Cross browser css/html

Tags: html, css, width

http://jsfiddle.net/stmpr/Ywq8G/3/

fiddle is simplified

as you can see the submenus are 1px to the left, but in my modern browser ie10, FF, chrome etc etc. It shows just correct.

But if i put: left:1px, then in modern browsers it would look ugly.

I want it to look nice in both older browsers and modern browsers.

```
code removed as requested
```

Comment: I would suggest to remove all irrelevant code and simplify your JSFiddle, to make it more clear what exactly the problem is and so we don't have to dig through all your code. Furthermore, from UX view: the submenu's are not really userfriendly and can disappear if the user moves his mouse too slowly to the next one.

Comment: yea i try to work with intervals on mouseover en reset on mouseenter, but thats not the case at this moment, but i couldnt just post the JSFiddle because SO didnt let me

Comment: What are the browsers that have this issue ?

Comment: Use (to be less specific) "browsers hacks", such as IE Hacks, FF Hacks and Chrome hacks to set your pixels or whatever on older browsers.

Comment: This is what you want http://jsfiddle.net/Ywq8G/4/ ?

Comment: yeah that is exactly what i want, but now it's correct in the fiddle, but in my modern browser it is 1 pixel to the right.

Answer (score 0):

The best I could think is to use a CCS stylesheet Fallback, you can create Browser specific stylesheets or styling, for instance if you want to have a Stylesheet specific for IE versions below IE10 you can use:

```
<!--[if (lte IE 10)]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/IEFallback.css" />
    <![endif]-->
```

lots of people are against using Fallbacks but I have found it to come quite handy in situations where you have no other choice, there are multiple browser style specific 'hacks' and browser specific styling for instance using webkit and so.

Hope this helps at all.

Comment: how can i test : <!--[if (lte IE 10)]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/IEFallback.css" />
    <![endif]-->     in IE Tester it doesnt seem to do anything, neither does it change the fiddle

Comment: This is usually used in code were you use external stylesheets, the comments aren't picked up by IE so it reads the line [if (lte IE 10)] which checks if the current version is lower than 10. (you can test it in IE by pressing f12 and selecting "browser Mode" and setting it to 9 or 8 for example. If that's what you're asking